# Animating cubes in a sequence with three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I am trying to replicate this effect as shown here: 
https://dribbble.com/shots/1783699-Blocks?list=users&offset=2

I have a bunch of cubes in 3d space, positioned along the x and z axis with loops - so far so good. What I can't get the hang of animating them in such specific order. I guess I shoud loop through them and scale each one of them along its Y axis with different timing, based on its position?

Secondly, I guess I should use setInterval() to trigger the animation sequence, but I dont know how to implement it...

I have this code right now for looping through the boxes and scaling them:

```
var r = -1;
(function f(){
    r = (r + 1) % cubes.length;
    cubes[r].scale.y += cubes[r].vy;
    if (cubes[r].scale.y >= 1.4) {
        cubes[r].vy *= -1;
}
setInterval(f, 200);
```

But this doesn't accomplish this wavy, step by step scaling...

Here's a link to what I currently have:
http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/NPGqqq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect in the demo you linked is essentially expressing a sine wave propagation.  If you want to achieve that, you'll want to scale your cubes in relation to a sine wave based on time and space parameters.

We'll start with time.  I recommend doing each of these steps individually, so you can see how they combine to produce the finished result.  The `requestAnimationFrame` callback takes a single parameter, a high-resolution animation time.  We can simply apply that to the cube height scale:

```
function drawFrame(ts) {
    requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
    render.render(scene, camera);
    cubes.forEach(function(c) {
        c.scale.y = Math.sin(ts/500) + 1;
    });
}
```

Note that we divide the timestamp `ts` by 500; this allows you to adjust the speed of the animation.  The timestamp is in milliseconds, so dividing by 500 means it will complete its cycle every 3.14 (pi) seconds.  If you want to to complete in N seconds, you would divide by 500*pi and multiply by N.

We also add 1 to the sine wave to make all of its values positive (normally, its range is [-1,1]; adding 1 brings its range to [0,2]).

Now we can start a "wave" by adding one of the dimensional components to the sine function.  We'll start, arbitrarily, with the x-dimension:

```
c.scale.y = Math.sin(ts/500 + c.position.x/4.95) + 1;
```

I found the 4.95 by trial and error; by adjusting that number, you can determine the "resolution" of the wave.  Bigger numbers mean smoother waves.

Then, finally, I added in the z-dimension:

```
c.scale.y = Math.sin(ts/500 + c.position.x/4.95 + c.position.z/12) + 1;
```

Again, I played around with the z-divider until I found a parameter that looked nice.

Here's your CodePen modified with this solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoYdGv

Comment: Man, thanks for your detailed explanation! I got the desired effect, you rock!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!  THREE.js is a lot of fun.